# Write a function in c that includes the following sequence of statements [Wont Compile]

Tags: java, c++, c, scope

There is a question in my programming languages textbook that is as follows:

> Write a C function that includes the
>   following sequence of statements:
>
> x = 21;
>   int x;
>   x = 42;
>
> Run the program and explain the
>   results. Rewrite the same code in C++
>   and Java and compare the results.

I have written code, and played with it in all three languages but I can not even get it to compile. This includes declaring x above the three lines as well as in the calling function (as this question is obviously attempting to illustrate scoping issues)

I'd like to explain the results and do the comparisons on my own, as it is an assignment question but I was wondering if anyone had any insight as to how to get this code to compile?

Thanks

Comment: Er, could you post what you have so far? That way someone can give you a pointer without revealing too much. PS. Kudos for not just demanding the answer to your homework ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note the following requires C99:

```
int x;

void foo()
{
    x = 21;
    int x;
    x = 42;
}
```

Since this is homework, you'll need to provide your own explanation.

Comment: That didn't want to compile for me. Likely because I didn't tell gcc to use C99. I'll give that a shot! Thanks.

Comment: @Cody - with gcc, you need to use the `-std=c99` option.

Comment: Just compiled, and it worked fine. Explanation is now very obvious. Thanks!